# Checking whether string is a sub-string or not

Tags: python, substring

I am trying to check whether the given a string is a sub-string of another string, and print the index value of string where the sub-string takes place.

So far I have this code. To reduce the complexity I am using single for loop.

```
s1 = "robot"
s2 = "bot"
for i in range(len(s2)):
            if s1[i] == s2[i]:
               i =i +1

            print(i)
```

Or alternatively I was thinking about this,

```
for i in range(len(s1)):
    for j in range(len(s2)):
       if s1[i] == s2[j]
                i = i+1
                j = j+1
       print(i)
```

I know we can use **`in`** keyword to solve this, but I want to learn the logic behind it.

Please help me. I am trying from a long time to solve these.

Comment: What is your question?  If these don't work, explain how they don't w/ sample input and output.  If they do, what are you asking?

Comment: Use python `str.find()`

Comment: [Here's the logic behind it.](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin string method [find()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) which will return the index of the substring, or -1 if not found.

```
>>> "robot".find("bot")
2
>>> "robot".find("Xbot")
-1
```

Comment: OP is aware of these, they are trying to implement it on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trash implementation:

```
a = 'pleb'
b = 'youreapleb'

def find(a, b):
  for i, c in enumerate(b):
    if a == b[i: i + len(a)]:
      return i

print find(a, b)
```

Comment: U are using i as a counter varaible, what is the role of "c" in here.

Comment: Hii I got it why u used c in there. Its there if we want to access the value at each counter variable. Thank you so much for your help.